# Optional Many-to-Many Relationship in Entity Framework Core 5+

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, .net-5

Context: .NET 5, EF Core 5, SQL Server

Problem: I need EF to `LEFT JOIN` an optional many-to-many relationship through the `Include().ThenInclude()` calls but it's only wanting to `INNER JOIN`. This results in missing rows when the relationship doesn't exist.

I have three tables: `A`, `B`, and `AB` that represents the many-to-many relationship between `A` and `B`. Below is a simplified version of the real tables but `AB` can have extra columns, so I don't want to use EF implicit relationships for it.

A

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| ... |

B

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| ... |

AB

| ID | AID | BID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

The C# models for them look like:

```cs
public class A
{
  public Guid ID { get; set; }

  public ICollection<AB> ABs { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class B
{
  public Guid ID { get; set; }

  public ICollection<AB> ABs { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class AB
{
  public Guid ID { get; set; }

  public Guid AID { get; set; }

  public Guid BID { get; set; }

  public A A { get; set; }

  public B B { get; set; }
}
```

Then the query I'm using to select the data out:

```cs
context.As
       .AsSplitQuery()
       .Include(f => f.ABs)
           .ThenInclude(f => f.B)
       .ToList();
```

These relationships all work fine when they exist. I can get from a given A to any of the Bs that are assigned to it in the `AB` table.

The problem happens when the `A` row doesn't have any corresponding rows in the `AB` table (ie. there are no `B`s assigned to it). When that happens, EF is turning my LINQ query into an `INNER JOIN`, which excludes all the As that don't have rows in the `AB` table.

From my research, EF Core 5 did away with explicit mandatory vs optional relationship hinting and now infers it from whether the navigation property in the model is nullable. But `ICollection`s are natively nullable, as is the `B` class I'm pointing it at. Even so, adding an `?` to mark any part of the property nullable doesn't change the generated SQL (eg. `public ICollection<AB>? ABs { get; set; }`)

I've tried specifying the relationship in the context, as per some other advice online but that didn't change the behavior:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
            .HasMany(f => f.Bs)
            .WithMany(f => f.As);
```

Is there any way (other than writing the joins manually) to force EF to treat the AB navigation property as optional?

---

Update:

This appears to be a side-effect of using `AsSplitQuery()`. Changing it to `AsSingleQuery()` correctly generates a `LEFT JOIN`.

I'm guessing it's something to do with my `ThenInclude()` loading a not-null one-to-many relationship in the split query. Would still be nice to know if this is a bug or if there's some way to tell EF that the upstream relationship is still optional, even though the downstream one isn't.

Comment: You need a left outer join to get left items when there isn't a right item.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: @jdweng I was hoping there was a way to massage EF to do the LEFT JOIN without writing the join manually, per the last sentence of my post. The rest of my app doesn't use the query syntax and people online seem to think EF can do LEFT JOIN just fine, as long as it thinks the navigation prop is nullable.

Comment: The Include should generate an OUTER JOIN. If it doesn't, it's a bug.

Comment: @GertArnold Then it's a bug that's seemingly only happening to me. As far as I'm aware, Include is supposed to create INNER JOINs for non-nullable navigation properties and LEFT JOINs for nullable ones. So it seems like EF thinks my ICollection property is non-nullable.

Comment: Includes for collections should always generate outer joins, because they can never be guaranteed to contain elements. Would you mind posting the exact code, or a [mre]? Because there may be something involved you weren't aware of while cutting down the code.

Comment: You can use a Where instead of a JOIN.